# what does the turtle.setworldcoordinates function do?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Beginner's Python book tend to grow more steep towards the middle pages and hardly explain anything at all. Therefore, I'm having a hard time figuiring out what the turtle.setworldcoordinates function does after being disappointed by my inability to do so by reading the documentation which was very unhelpful and not being able to empirically deduce anything with some ideas of the documentation. Could anyone please point out what this function does in turtle graphics?

Comment: See the pictures of how the star distorts in [the slide section 2.1 here](https://python-turtle-demo.googlecode.com/files/SevenWaysToUseTurtle-PyCon2009.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since turtle.py comes with Python, and is written in Python, you can look at the source to see what the function does (which I find I do a lot with turtle.py)  See below.

I believe `setworldcoordinates()` allows you to select a coordinate system that's more convenient for your problem.  For example, suppose you don't want (0,0) in the center of the screen.  Instead of incorporating an offset, you can use `setworldcoordinates()` to move it to a corner if that works better for you.  You can also set up coordinate systems that have a different scaling factor in the horizontal vs. the verical.

For example see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224422/python-turtle-positional-errors/36660290#36660290) where I define a routine that uses `setworldcoordinates()` to scale anything you draw without you having to incorporate any scaling factor into your own drawing code.

Or you can set a coordinate system with corners at (0,0), (1,0), (0,1) and (1,1) to work completely within the unit square.

The tricky bit is it maps your coordinate system onto the existing window shape -- so you either have to adjust your coordinates to the window or reshape the window to match your coordinate system.  Otherwise you might find yourself with an undesirable aspect ratio.

```
def setworldcoordinates(self, llx, lly, urx, ury):
    """Set up a user defined coordinate-system.

    Arguments:
    llx -- a number, x-coordinate of lower left corner of canvas
    lly -- a number, y-coordinate of lower left corner of canvas
    urx -- a number, x-coordinate of upper right corner of canvas
    ury -- a number, y-coordinate of upper right corner of canvas

    Set up user coodinat-system and switch to mode 'world' if necessary.
    This performs a screen.reset. If mode 'world' is already active,
    all drawings are redrawn according to the new coordinates.

    But ATTENTION: in user-defined coordinatesystems angles may appear
    distorted. (see Screen.mode())

    Example (for a TurtleScreen instance named screen):
    >>> screen.setworldcoordinates(-10,-0.5,50,1.5)
    >>> for _ in range(36):
    ...     left(10)
    ...     forward(0.5)
    """
    if self.mode() != "world":
        self.mode("world")
    xspan = float(urx - llx)
    yspan = float(ury - lly)
    wx, wy = self._window_size()
    self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)
    oldxscale, oldyscale = self.xscale, self.yscale
    self.xscale = self.canvwidth / xspan
    self.yscale = self.canvheight / yspan
    srx1 = llx * self.xscale
    sry1 = -ury * self.yscale
    srx2 = self.canvwidth + srx1
    sry2 = self.canvheight + sry1
    self._setscrollregion(srx1, sry1, srx2, sry2)
    self._rescale(self.xscale/oldxscale, self.yscale/oldyscale)
    self.update()
```

> my book gives a weird example like this: setworldcoordinates(-10, 0.5,
>   1, 2), could you tell me what this operation exactly does?

These weird examples of `setworldcoordinates()` abound but explain little, see @TessellatingHeckler's slide for example.  They just show that you can do extreme things with the coordinates.  But to answer your followup question, if we have a 100 by 100 window, this is what that particular call would do to our coordinate system:

[image]

Comment: I'm still a really very beginner at programming. I understood the part before the code but my book gives a weird example like this:       setworldcoordinates(-10, 0.5, 1, 2), could you tell me what this operation exactly does?

Comment: @lind, I've added a picture to show what that the call `setworldcoordinates(-10, 0.5, 1, 2)` would do to the turtle screen's coordinate system.

Comment: I'm sorry and this must be frustrating that I'm being too persistent but what is the mathematical relationship that guides the input and output of the coords; since I can't fully read the code above. :-)

Comment: where did the self.mode() come from. I mean, it's neither defined nor imported. It doesn't seem to be a built-in. and I imported everything from turtle and still no sign of it. Could you please clarify that

Comment: could you atleast tell me where the self.mode() came from or what it does?

Comment: @lind `mode()` is a method of the turtle screen: `turtle.Screen().mode()`  It's in the turtle documentation under "Settings and special methods".  The default mode is 'standard', the others are 'logo' and 'world'.  It is used to determine which turtle model to use, e.g. emulate Logo.  This affects the default heading, whether positive angles go clockwise or counterclockwise, etc.

Comment: if turtle.fd(1), and turtle.fd(0.5) result the same increment on the canvas then what is the significance of using floating points?

Comment: plus, how does the window suddenly distort in the aforementioned slide?

Comment: So, setworldcoordinates(-width/2.0, -height/2.0, width/2.0, height/2.0) with width =1 and height =1 would mean to set the 4 corners of the coordinate system to be (-1,1), (1,1), (-1,-1) and (1,-1)? Right?

Comment: @study, no your `setworldcoordinates()` incantation would set the corners of the coordinate system to (-0.5, 0.5)[upper left], (0.5, 0.5)[upper right], (-0.5, -0.5)[lower left] and (0.5, -0.5)[lower right].  Try it interactively and see.

Comment: I see. Thank you.